# How do I FlexUnit Test Parsley commands?

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm, flexunit4, parsley

I needed some guidance on how to use FlexUnit 4 within Flash Builder, to unit test a Parsley-frameworked Flex application.

I have tried lookign at one or two sites but with no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Insync sample application made by Adobe :

http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/cairngorm3/trunk/samples/insync/

There are some examples of testing commands